# Continuity upon trivial topology

Tags: general-topology

I am puzzled with the following statement: "Given any map $f:X\to Y$ where $X$   is equiped with the trivial topology $(\varnothing,X)$, then this map is continuous iff $Y$ has the trivial topology. (This can be found [M.Gemignani - Elementary Topology](http://books.google.fr/books?id=q8TttGzVGxUC&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false), p70, §4.3, Example 8,). When the topology on $Y$ is not trivial, the author says that "the preimage by any map $f$ of a non-trivial open set (which exists) is not trivial (nor $\varnothing$  nor $X$)...hence the preimage is not an open subset, therefor $f$ could not be continuous".

Consider the constant map example: say $f(x)=a$, then $f^{-1}(U)=X$ where $U$  in any open set containing $a$,   where as $f^{-1}(U)=\varnothing$ if $a\not\in U$ and we have checked that the preimage of any open set is open in $X$   since $X$   has the trivial topology. Then, any topology on $Y$ - trivial or not - makes the constant map continuous.

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pay attention he said the function f is "onto"!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now this makes sense. "Given any surjective map $f:X→Y$ where $X$ is equiped with the trivial topology (∅,X), then this map is continuous iff $Y$ has the trivial topology".

Comment: Indeed, and the text does say onto. Which is a common synonym for being surjective.